# Which WPF radio button is checked. Not using if/then

Tags: wpf, radio-button

Is there a way to find out which radio button is checked in WPF, similar to how this is done in regular forms code:

```
Control rb = gbTop.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

I have a lot of radio buttons, and would rather not have to check for each one with an "if".

The Groupbox control doesn't seem to have a Controls property.  I don't see any other way to see what's in them.
I could use a different "grouping" container if that works better.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  Should have used a stackpanel, and then this code, a slight variation of the above.

```
Control rb = StackPnl.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.IsChecked == true);
```